# Toolbar custom UIBarButtonItem position and width

Tags: ios, storyboard, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I have a layout with toolbar at the bottom of the screen. There are 3 custom buttons in it: play, refresh and one that I am using to show two labels.

[image]

3rd button has a view that width is set to fit for 3.5 but I can't set constraints on it and it keeps the same width on bigger screens so labels are not centered in toolbox.

[image]

How to stretch a volumeView and labels to get the full available width? Or center it on available empty space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have removed auto layout and used autoresizing.